# Calculating how likely something happens k times with given average frequency

Tags: probability, statistics

There is some event happening randomly, but on average $N$ times a minute. $N$ is unknown, but we have an educated guess that it might be $N=N_0$. We make an observation that the event took place $k$ times during the last minute. How to calculate the likelihood of seeing the event $k$ or some less likely number of times, if $N=N_0$? In other words, how exceptional seeing $k$ was or how likely it is that our guess $N=N_0$ was wrong?

Please, feel free to help me formulate my question with more accurate terminology. I'm not really confident with the difference of probability vs. likelihood etc...

Comment: Happening randomly needs some extra definition, but it may be a Poisson process and if so you could use a Poisson distribution

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right and it might indeed be a Poisson process. Helps me forward. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this could be a problem for hypothesis testing.

$$H_0: N=N_0\\
H_1:N\ne N_0$$

or if $k>N_0$, for a one-sided test,

$$H_0: N\le N_0\\
H_1: N>N_0$$

Then the p-value is the smallest level of significance $\alpha_0$ that we would reject the null hypothesis.